# How to improve Angular dropdown menu performance

Tags: angular, frontend

I am working on improving code performance, below code snippet is what I received to work on. The options have 10k items, the websites freeze for few secs rendering the dropdown menu. Any suggestion on improving this? The 10k choices are there for business reasons.

```
<select multiple class="col-md-2 form-control form-control-sm" id="">
          <option *ngFor="let option of options; let i=index" [value]="i+1">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You're looking for "virtualization". Basically, you only add the items that are currently visible to the DOM; you only have 20 or so `<option>` elements rendered at a time. There are libraries to help with this or you can write your own handling.

Comment: This is close, but depends on `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk`. [Cdk virtual-scroll inside mat-select for mat-option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266444/cdk-virtual-scroll-inside-mat-select-for-mat-option)